# Create a chart with 5 lines, despite Salesforce's limitation of 2

Tags: lightning, reporting, charts, report-chart

I have a custom object with fields:

1. Date
2. Measurement A
3. Measurement B
4. Measurement C
5. Measurement D
6. Measurement E

I want to create a line graph with X-axis: the date (field 1) and 5 lines, for fields 2 - 6.
For some insane reason, Salesforce limits the number of Y values to just 2! But: when grouping data, it is possible to create graphs that have an arbitrary amount of Y values.

Is there some way in which I can create a grouping on my object that allows me to create a 5-line chart? I am using plain Lightning, not the Analytics license.

Update: I found the free Lightning Web Chart.js Component in the AppExchange, but to display more than one line in a graph, you need to code in JS. Simply using it with app builder is not an option with dynamic data.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind static graphs (i.e., not interactive, you can still dynamically generate them), you could look at https://quickchart.io/ which allows you to create graphs images given a bunch of JSON parameters